# How do I Import cx_Oracle on CentOS 6?

Tags: django, centos, mod-wsgi, cx-oracle, centos6

I´m having serious trouble to get Django to work with my Apache/mod_wsgi installation accessing Oracle. I have this setup running on a CentOS 6 host, and I'm getting this error in my Apache logs:

```
Error loading cx_Oracle module: libclntsh.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I try to import `cx_Oracle` from the Python command line it works fine in both root and apache users. I set `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (`$ORACLE_HOME/lib`) correctly: in `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf`, `~/.bash_profile`, anywhere I can set an env var.

I've also tried making a hard link or symbolic link to `$ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1` in `/usr/lib`, but I got a permission error, no matter how many `chmod 777` I issue from `/usr` down to `/usr/lib` and the file.

I added the `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` with no change.

Apparently this error occurs only when the Apache user runs the import cx_Oracle command, although logging in with this user I can run the command from the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build cx_Oracle from source code, set the LD_RUN_PATH environment variable to the path to the lib directory containing Oracle .so files and it will embed the location in the cx_Oracle .so and will know where to get libclntsh.so at runtime without needing LD_LIBRARY_PATH set.

Comment: I've already built cx_Oracle without that option. So can I just set that var and rebuild it and it should work or should I remove it first before rebuilding?

Comment: You need to start from clean cx_Oracle source code to ensure doesn't use version already built. Variable needs to be set and exported in user environment. Once done with building/installing cx_Oracle, unset the variable as not needed after that.

Comment: Still does'nt work. I get the same error message. How do I know which Python Apache uses to run WSGI? Anyway, I can run the command `import cx_Oracle` as apache, which is the strangest to me.

Comment: How could I fix this:

I've also tried making a hard link or symbolic link to $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1 in /usr/lib, but I got a permission error, no matter how many chmod 777 I issue from /usr down to /usr/lib and the file. 

I've seen this solution in another blog post and it worked there.

Comment: Solved!!! It was the damned SELINUX blocking the execution of the libs! I've set `/usr/sbin/setenforce 0` and `/etc/selinux/config` to disabled. Works Fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution without reinstalling..
"appended /app/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf and ran ldconfig." from
http://catherinedevlin.blogspot.com/2005/10/cxoracle-and-ubuntu.html